# NoSuchMethodError with C++ method to Java Native Interface

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, nosuchmethoderror

I am working on creating a JNI and Java class so that I can use C++ class in JVM.
However, I got into a problem where the program compiled just fine but at runtime, the method is just invisible.
Here is the C++ in the original class

```
bool TraceLog::getLogs(std::vector<ByteArray> &vecLogs, unsigned int uiNumLines)
{
    bool bRet = VersionCheck::check(tServer, tError);

    unsigned int uiContId = 0;
    if (bRet)
        bRet = getChunk(uiContId, uiNumLines, vecLogs);

    while (bRet && uiContId > 0)
    {
        std::vector<ByteArray> vecChunk;
        bRet = getChunk(uiContId, uiNumLines, vecChunk);
        if (bRet)
            vecLogs.insert(vecLogs.end(), vecChunk.begin(), vecChunk.end());
    }

    return bRet;
}
```

Here is the JNI I wrote

```
//fxcl.hsm.log.TraceLog.getLogs
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_fxcl_hsm_log_TraceLog_getLogs
    (JNIEnv *ptEnv, jobject ptObj, jobject tVecLogs, jint tUiNumLines)
    {
     TraceLog& tLog=getDevice(*ptEnv, ptObj);
      std::vector<ByteArray> vecLogs;
      int uiNumLines=static_cast<unsigned int>(tUiNumLines);
      tLog.getLogs(vecLogs, uiNumLines);

      //convert to a vector of Java objects
      std::vector<jobject> vecJavaLogs;
      vecJavaLogs.reserve(vecLogs.size());
      for (auto iter = vecLogs.begin(); iter < vecLogs.end(); ++iter)
        vecJavaLogs.push_back(JniConvert::byteArray_uncast(*ptEnv, *iter));
      tVecLogs= JniObjectSet::toJava(*ptEnv, vecJavaLogs, "java/util/ArrayList");
    }
```

Here is the method in the Java class

```
public native boolean getLogs(ArrayList<byte[]> vecLogs, int uiNumLines)
        throws ConnectionException;
```

Has anyone encountered such issue?
Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you load the C++ library into the JVM?

Comment: Yes I did. I have a makefile where the .so library is pointed to the file for compilation and execution

Comment: do you hava Java code which tells the JVM to load the .so file?

Comment: What is the classname of the native method you are trying to implement? The classname in your comment disagrees with the classname in your native function name.

Comment: Also note that assigning to `tVecLogs` is useless.

Comment: The class name is TraceLog. Oh, I forgot to update the comment. The function name is correct.

Comment: I think my main problem is to pass the data from original C++ to that tVecLogs so that I can use it in the Java. However, it's a reference of a vector of byte array, so I find it difficult to do it.

Comment: Please edit your question with the full error produced by Java as well as the output of `nm mylibrary.so`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to load your library with the [System.loadLibrary](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)).

Example:

```
class TraceLog {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("name");
    }

    public native boolean getLogs(ArrayList<byte[]> vecLogs, int uiNumLines)
        throws ConnectionException;
}
```

where `name` corresponds to the name of your native library. For libfoo.so, it would be `System.loadLibrary("foo");`

If you already are doing it, please post the whole exception message.